# How can I set column show once in detail band on jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm designing a jasper report.
I tried to set the database data to the detail band but I want the left column just show once in the report, and merge vertical to one column.

I want to design the detail section to show like the picture below.

[excpet report result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVSZK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This issue doesn't need the code just use the iReport3.0.0 to edit the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I solve the problem, to set the element to "Relative to band height" then use java to run the report do not use preview then you can get the except result.

[soluction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3kEB.png)